# Как спозиционировать блоки с помощью float?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Подскажите как спозиционировать блоки main и sub с помощью флоата, имя вот такой код:

```css
.clearfix:after{
content:"";
display: table;
clear:both;
}

.main{
  background-color:red;
  width:100px;
  position:relative;
float:left;
}

.main div{
    position:absolute;
}

.sub{
  background-color:green;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="main clearfix">
  <div>12312321321</div>
  <div>12312321321</div>
  <div>12312321321</div>
</div>
<div class="sub clearfix">
  <div>asd</div>
  <div>asd</div>
  <div>asd</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Float устаревшее решение для позиционирования.
Его используют для обтекания какого-то изображения.
Лучше использовать **flexbox**, **grid** или другие методы для позиционирования.

Вот пример на flexbox:

```css
.main {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
}

.list {
  padding: 10px;
  background: green;
}

.sublist {
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
}

.item {
  color: #272727;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sublist">
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать на стандартных инлайн блоках:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sub {
  background: red;
}

.main {
  background: green;
}

main {
  font-size: 0;
}

main>div {
  font-size: 16px;
}

main>div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="main">
    <div>Hello, world</div>
    <div>Hello, world</div>
    <div>Hello, world</div>
  </div>

  <div class="sub">
    <div>Hello, world</div>
    <div>Hello, world</div>
    <div>Hello, world</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Или на grid можно так. В перспективе лучше выбрать grid, но не забывайте, что grid не так давно получил поддержку браузерами. Хотя "не так давно" - понятие растяжимое)

```css
.main {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 100px;
  display: grid; /* GRID */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); /* две колонки */
}

.list {
  padding: 10px;
  background: green;
}

.sublist {
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
}

.item {
  color: #272727;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sublist">
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  </div>
</div>
```